# Data loss in AWS Elastic Cache

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

We are using AWS Elastic cache with clustered mode and 3 nodes.

We don't use persistence with AWS Elastic cache hence we don't have backup /restore of the data stored.

So, i would like to understand what is the probability of losing my data in my setup. I assume this will only happen if all the nodes go down ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 3):

Amazon ElastiCache's data loss is usually caused by a downed primary node. Either the entire database or a partial one can be lost, depending on whether the primary node had synced replicas.

- When one of the replicas was synced during the primary node failure, no data will be lost, and the synced replica may act as new primary.
- The replica with the most updated database will become the primary if none of the replicas were completely synced, meaning that all the data not yet populated from the primary will be lost.
- In the event that you don't have any replicas, the primary node will fail, resulting in the loss of all data up to your most recent snapshot.

In [Amazon ElastiCache Fault Tolerance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/FaultTolerance.html) you may find that in order to minimize the impact of a node failure, AWS recommends that you use multiple nodes in each shard and distribute them across multiple availability zones. AWS recommends that you enable Multi-AZ on your replication group when running Redis, so that ElastiCache will fail over automatically to a replica in case of a primary node failure.

If you cannot afford any data loss, Amazon offers MemoryDB for Redis, which solves the above problem. Using MemoryDB for Redis, you can create a durable, in-memory database that performs extremely fast.
You can read more about MemoryDB for redis here
[What is memorydb for redis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/what-is-memorydb-for-redis.html).